# Set Taxonomy based on post status

Tags: functions, actions

I am setting a taxonomy based on the post_status. It works as needed except I want to allow the taxonomy to be overridden if a particular taxonomy is selected.

Here is the code

```
function add_categories_automatically($postID) {
    if(get_post_status($postID) == 'draft'){
        $catsID = array(1); //active
        wp_set_post_categories($postID, $catsID);
    }
    if(get_post_status($postID) == 'publish'){
        $catsID = array(5); //complete
        wp_set_post_categories($postID, $catsID);
    }
    if(get_post_status($postID) == 'publish' && has_category( 'billed' ) ){
        $catsID = array(16); //billed
        wp_set_post_categories($postID, $catsID);
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'add_categories_automatically');
```

On the last if statement I have tried to use && to set a new category if the post is published AND the category billed is selected. It just keeps being set as id 5 from the previous if statement.

Any ideas on how I can make the last if statement work?

Comment: Try passing the post ID into the `has_category()` check since you're not in the loop.

Comment: @WebElaine that makes sense, any clues on how I would actually do that? :)

Comment: Change `has_category( 'billed' )` to `has_category( 'billed', $postID )`.

Comment: @WebElaine That also defaulted to the category above, but I then tried setting a variable for all the post statuses and has_category matching. I will post below, it works but if I'm doing something that doesn't make sense please let me know. Thanks for your input, appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what works with the help of WebElaine above. I had to pass the postID to `has_category()` and then set variables.

```
function add_categories_automatically($postID) {
    $p_published = get_post_status($postID) == 'publish';
    $p_draft = get_post_status($postID) == 'draft';
    $p_cat = has_category( 'billed', $postID);  
    
    if ($p_draft == 'draft'){
        $catsID = array(1); //active
        wp_set_post_categories($postID, $catsID);
    }
    if ($p_published == 'publish'){
        $catsID = array(5); //complete
        wp_set_post_categories($postID, $catsID);
    }
    if($p_published == 'publish' && $p_cat ){
        $catsID = array(16); //billed
        wp_set_post_categories($postID, $catsID);
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'add_categories_automatically');
```